# How to serve a continuously running python script to multiple users (Social Media Bot)

Tags: python, web-services, automation, httprequest, scale

I hope you are all having an amazing day. So I am working on a project using Python. The script's job is to automate actions and tasks on a social media platform via http requests. As of now, one instance of this script access one user account. Now, I want to create a website where I can let users register, enter their credentials to the social media platform and run an instance of this script to perform the automation tasks. I've thought about creating a new process of this script every time a new user has register, but this doesn't seem efficient. Also though about using threads, but also does not seem reasonable. Especially if there are 10,000 users registering. What is the best way to do this? How can I scale? Thank you guys so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the nature of the tasks that you're running?

Are the tasks simply jobs that run at a scheduled time of day, or every X minutes? For this, you could have your Web application register cronjobs or similar, and each cronjob can spawn an instance of your script, which I assume is short-running, to carry out a the automated task one user at a time. If the exact timing of the script doesn't matter then you could scatter the running of these scripts throughout the day, on seperate machines if need be.

The above approach probably won't scale well to 10,000 users, and you will need something more robust, especially if the script is something that needs to run continuously (e.g. you are polling some data from Facebook and need to react to its changes). If it's a lot of communication per user, then you could consider using a producer-consumer model, where a bunch of producer scripts (which run continously) issue work requests into a global queue that a bunch of consumer scripts poll and carry out. You could also load balance such consumers and producers across multiple machines.

Of course, you would definitely want to squeeze out some parallelism from the extra cores of your machines by carrying out this work on multiple threads or processes. You could do this quite easily in Python using the multiprocessing module.

Comment: Thank yo so much for you reply. I have been trying to research this problem endlessly with no success. Let me be more specific here so that you understand the problem. This script as of now, will take one users credentials to an Instagram account, (a social media platform where users post pictures and others can "heart" the post and comment and follow other users). The bot is then responsible for liking posts of similar niche to the users account using a few strategies I have researched. This is done continuously throughout the day 24/7 for each user at a rate of about 200 likes per hour .

Comment: This is done at random times throughout the hour. Every few seconds. This is done with HTTP requests. This can easily be done using 1 account, but the issue is scaling to thousands of users.

Comment: You should have a swarm of continously running Web servers that perform the logic you need. The instances can be identical apart from some initialisation logic which should depend on the instance being initialised. Each instance can be responsible for executing the logic for some subset of your entire registered user list. For example: let's say you have 9 users registered. You can run three instances of your application with the first instance responsible for users 1-3, the second 4-6 and the third 7-9. There should also be a mechanism for each instance to discover any newly registered users.

Comment: In terms of how you'd implement this, one idea is to spawn each instance of your Web server and give it a unique ID. The hash of this ID can determine which subset of users that instance is responsible for. You can then fetch information about only those users from your database or persistance layer you're using. Ideally the logic used to decide on each subset should be aware of how many instances exist in total in order to balance the users evenly across all instances.

Comment: This will all be dependent on how you're actually deploying the application. I was writing this with something like Docker swarm or Kubernetes in mind, but anything which allows you to manage multi-instance deployments of your application will suffice.

Comment: ah, okay so is it multi instances of the web server itself or just multi instances of the program?

Comment: Upon reading more about Docker Swarm, I realize this may be the solution that I need to accomplish this. Thank you very much @Norbo11 I would have such a long time to discover such a solution!